# Reledmac spaces on footnotes linenumbers and lemma

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, linenumber, lemma

Is there a way to make the line numbers of a footnote as a single block? 
Please see image below, I would like to print the two line numbers in the same line something like

`18~\textendash{}~21`

[image]

And, in the same time, can the space between line numbers and lemma be a non-breackable space (see here line numbers 55-57 on one line and the lemma on the next line, can those be printed together)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid line break after dash, you must set `\Xlinerangeseparator`(§ 7.2.5 of the handbook).

```
\Xlinerangeseparator{\nolinebreak\textnormal{--}\nolinebreak}
```

To avoid line break after line number, use `\Xnonbreakableafternumber` (§ 7.2.12 of the handbook).